# How to return an object from a JavaScript function and access that returned object?

Tags: javascript

In the follow code below, I am looking to access the environment object that the getEnvironment function returns. How would I go about accessing this object somewhere else in my code?

```
window.EXAMPLE = {

        config : {
            local: 'http://localhost:8888/example',
            staging_v2: 'http://example.com/staging',
            production: 'http://example.com',
            image_path: '/images/',

        },

        getEnvironment : function () {
            if (window.location.href.indexOf(EXAMPLE.config.local) > -1) {
                var environment = {
                    path : EXAMPLE.config.local + EXAMPLE.config.image_path,
                }
                return environment;
            }

            if (window.location.href.indexOf(EXAMPLE.config.staging_v2) > -1) {
                var environment = {
                    path : EXAMPLE.config.staging_v2 + EXAMPLE.config.image_path,
                }
                return environment;
            }

            if (window.location.href.indexOf(EXAMPLE.config.production) > -1) {

                var environment = {
                    path : EXAMPLE.config.production + EXAMPLE.config.image_path,
                }
                return environment;
            }
        },

    }
```

Comment: Please take the time to clearly describe your problem in words, instead of just dumping a block of code and expecting others to guess what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Can you clarify? If you return an object from a function, you can access that object normally. E.g. `someFunc().propOfObject;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object returned by a method or function behaves no differently than any other object. Here is an example of using the `environment` object returned by the method in your example:

```
var env = EXAMPLE.getEnvironment();
console.log(env.path);
```